# Express JS 4: exported routes and session

Tags: node.js, session, routes, express-4

i'm quite new to node and i've been working through this issue for some hours now but am failing at finding a solution :/
Perhaps u can help me :)

I have exported my routes out of the app.'s into routes.js. There i am having a POST for a Login-process. When loged in, i want to pass the userid from a databank into the session for later use (e.g. socket io).
How do i have to construct this?
I have tried several setups but i don't seem to get it.

**app.js**

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var sessionStore = new session.MemoryStore();
app.use(cookieParser('lts session'));
app.use(session({ secret: 'lts session', cookie: { maxAge: 600000 }, store : sessionStore}));
var router = require('./modules/routes.js');
app.use(router);
```

**routes.js**

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    ....
    req.session.name =  admins[id].name;
    req.session.userId = id;
    ...
};
```

Later on i control my session by logging sessionStore.

Comment: It might help future readers if you outline what "setups" you tried and how they do not solve your problem

Comment: Have you looked at [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)?

Comment: I am using express-session.

My problem ist that those req.session vars aren't saved.
Right now I am using app.post etc instead of router.post....
still no progress :/

Answer (score 0):

If u manipulate your session-vars, then just use:

```
req.session.save()
```

This will save your session-manipulation. 
Example:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  ....
  req.session.name =  admins[id].name;
  req.session.userId = id;
  req.session.save()
  ...
};
```